# Getting updated Shared Object data without reopening it

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, shared-objects

I have 2 swf that will be loaded on a website. One suppose to generate a bytearray and being passed over to another swf.

The problem is that when I save the bytearray to a SharedObject in user's local file, the second swf doesn't get the updated variable value from the first swf.

I've set the second swf to retrieve the value every one second and it don't get updated until I reload the page.

I flushed and close the connection to make sure the data is saved on the local path and that is not helping as well.

I also considered using LocalConnection as well but there is a bug in flash player for mac that stopping it to work between swfs on mac. Left me no choice but to use SharedObject for my project.

Do you guys have any solution for this?

Many thanks..

Comment: Never used SO to share data between SWF's at run-time, so not really experienced in that, but did you flush the data ?
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush()

Comment: Can ExternalInterface be a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7341721/1024132

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this approach will work (the local SharedObject probably isn't designed with this in mind, and the exact behavior might differ between browsers and flash player versions).

I would try using LocalConnection instead.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

EDIT: Sorry, I missed this: 
"I also considered using LocalConnection as well but there is a bug in flash player for mac that stopping it to work between swfs on mac. Left me no choice but to use SharedObject for my project."

I use local connection on mac all the time, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. I would strongly recommend using a random number that is generated once per page view and send it to the flash (to use as a part of the connection name), to ensure that you don't open several connections with the same name (if the user opens your site several times in different tabs for example).

Answer (score 0):

I use this method of communication without problem and it's works fine. Do you call flush after changing the value?